# Use stock keyboard as template for custom iOS 8 keyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, keyboard, ios8

I was wondering if it is possible to get the stock Apple keyboard design as a file to make a own custom keyboard with only slight changes to the original one.

I would like to only change one Key and was hoping that I don't have to build the whole design myself and try to imitate the original design.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Apple does not provide access or source code of the default keyboard. They do provide a [Custom Keyboard Template](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH16-SW7)

Comment: Found that one already. Thanks anyway, at least now I know I have no other way ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built a custom keyboard with the same look as the system keyboard (except it has only one "letter" key!): https://github.com/acoomans/ACKeyboard

I'm sure you can start from there and adapt it to your need. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

There is another custom keyboard with all the keys here. Looks like the might be a bit hacked together but could be another good place to start. https://github.com/archagon/tasty-imitation-keyboard